# Mongoose multiple queries return after second query

Tags: node.js, json, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

I am trying to get back 'image' with username and url properties included, but it seems that the first query returns first. Apologies for my rookie knowledge.

```
exports.getImg = (req, res) => {
    Image.find({}, '-__v').lean().exec((err, images) => {
        if (err) {
            res.sendStatus(400)({ 'msg': 'Something went wrong' });
        }
        
        for (let i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
           //trying to get 
            User.findOne({ _id: images[i].id}, (err, user) => {
                images[i]['username'] = user.uname;
                images[i]['url'] = req.protocol + '://' + req.get('host') + '/images/' + images[i]._id;
            });
        }
        // console.log(images);
        // res.json(images);
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is due the reason that, .find() function is asynchronous.As you are looping and also using .find() in the loop so it will not give the desrired result. You need to use async/await.

```
exports.getImg = async (req, res) => {
Image.find({}, '-__v').lean().exec(async(err, images) => {
    if (err) {
        res.sendStatus(400)({ 'msg': 'Something went wrong' });
    }       
    for (let i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
       //trying to get 
        await User.findOne({ _id: images[i].id}, (err, user) => {
            images[i]['username'] = user.uname;
            images[i]['url'] = req.protocol + '://' + req.get('host') + '/images/' + images[i]._id;
        });
    }
    // console.log(images);
    // res.json(images);
})
```

}

Comment: Hi thanks, for your help but i have "SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function" as error.